# Condition for $ SF(x^n-a/\mathbb{Q}) = SF(x^n+a/\mathbb{Q}) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

Despite it might be silly question, I'm eager to know it

Let the $ SF(x^n-a/\mathbb{Q})$ and  $SF(x^n+a/\mathbb{Q}) $   be the  splitting field of the $x^n-a$  and    $x^n+a$  over the $\mathbb{Q}$ respectively. The $n $ is a natural number.

say $\omega = e^{ \frac{2\pi i }{n}}$, $\alpha = (-a)^{ \frac{1}{n}}  $ And say $\beta =a^{ \frac{1}{n}}$

Then, $ SF(x^n-a/\mathbb{Q})= \mathbb{Q}(  \beta , \omega  ) $

on the other hand, $ SF(x^n+a/\mathbb{Q})= \mathbb{Q}(  \alpha , \omega ) $

I've considered the $n$ is a odd case. Since the  $(-1)^{ \frac{1}{n}} = -1 $ in either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ so $\alpha = -\beta $ in splitting fields over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Therefore my conclusion is If  the $n$  is odd number  then, $ SF(x^n-a/\mathbb{Q}) = SF(x^n+a/\mathbb{Q}) $.

Is my guess and conclusion right? Are there any other conditions for claiming $ SF(x^n-a/\mathbb{Q}) = SF(x^n+a/\mathbb{Q}) $ generally ?

Thanks for reading my post

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2682975/galois-group-of-xn1-over-bbb-q) for $a=1$. The splitting field of $x^n+1$ is $\Bbb Q (\zeta_{2n})$, and the one of $x^n-1$ is $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$. Then use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2942171/mathbb-q-zeta-m-cap-mathbb-q-zeta-n-mathbb-q-zeta-d?noredirect=1&lq=1). Or just see that for $n$ odd we have $\Phi_{2n}(X)=\Phi_n(-X)$.

Comment: For general $a$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx) and [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376267/splitting-field-for-xna). From these posts you should be able to answer your question. I am hesitating to write an answer, since repeating known answers is frowned upon.